# adding pg search to index page but having pundit issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit, pg-search

im trying to add pg search to my tweets index page, to search for tweets and users, however im having some pundit issues when i search. I've tried to set my tweet policy to return true on the index page but nothing changes.  ive tried to look on pundit documentation, but i cant seem to find anything. thanks. edit: i have added authorize @tweet in the index method but still doesnt work[image]

```html
class Tweet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_votable
  validates :content,
    presence: true,
    length: {maximum: 50},
    on: :create,
    allow_nil: false

    include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :global_search,
    against: [ :content ],
    associated_against: {
      user: [ :first_name, :last_name , :username]
    },
    using: {
      tsearch: { prefix: true }
    }
end
```

```html
<%= form_tag tweets_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query,
    params[:query],
    class: "form-control",
    placeholder: "Find a tweet or user"
  %>
<% end %>
```

```html
   def index
    # @tweets = Tweet.all.order("created_at DESC")
    # @tweets = policy_scope(Tweet).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 7).order('created_at DESC')

    if params[:query].present?
      @tweets = Tweet.global_search(params[:query])
    else
    @tweets = policy_scope(Tweet).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 7).order('created_at DESC')

    end
    @tweet = Tweet.new
    @user = current_user
  end
```

```html
class TweetPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      scope.all
    end
  end

  def index?
    return true
  end

  def create?
    return true
  end

  def upvote?
    return true
  end

def downvote?
    return true
  end
  def update?
    record.user == user
    # - record: the restaurant passed to the `authorize` method in controller
    # - user:   the `current_user` signed in with Devise.
  end

  def destroy?
    record.user == user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out. i didnt add policy scope to the other part of the if else statement in the tweets controller index method.